# API Gateway binary-data option not working with Lambda+Proxy integration

Tags: aws-api-gateway

This is yet another variation of "binary data not working", slightly different from existing questions.

I have defined a Lambda-Proxy Integration:

[image]

And I have enabled the option in the settings:

[image]

And I use `curl -H` to make a request with the proper `Accept` header, and you can also see the proper header in the response:

[image]

**So why is the final response still base-64 encoded?**